# Set line spacing in tcolorbox

Tags: line-spacing, tcolorbox

My entire document is double spaced. But I want the content in my `\tcolorbox` to be single spaced. Is this possible? I am not seeing anything in the documentation regarding line spacing.

Comment: How did you set double space?

Comment: A global \doublespacing command, part of the setspace package (i think)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `code` key provided by `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
  \noindent
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,boxsep=3pt,code={\singlespacing}]
    \kant[2]
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding comment, the following works for me

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  boxsep=3pt,
  code={\singlespacing},
  #1} 
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
  \noindent
  \begin{mybox}
    \kant[2]
  \end{mybox}
  \kant[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, this works. At least I can reproduce your example. Now to try to piece this into my current document and find out what it's conflicting with. (I put just the code= piece in and it wouldn't compile)

Comment: Ah, i see. I want the singlespacing definition in the \newtcolorbox statement, so I don't have to define it each time. Simply copying boxsep and code= into the \newtcolorbox [] options is what's throwing the error.  

-How can I specify singlespace as a default option in \newtcolorbox?

Comment: @RobinJ Please see the update.

Comment: Yes! I see the correlation between adding options at the time the box is called and the initial definition. Thanks tons!
Worked exactly the way I want.

Comment: This also causes the paragraph before the `tcolorbox` to be single-spaced, if no empty lines have been left between the `tcolorbox` and the paragraph. (You need to use raw text, rather than lipsum text to observe this.) How to prevent this?